# Can I get a log of optimizations applied by the compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

When compiling a C++ application or library with optimizations turned on, like `-O3` for gcc, is there a way to get the applied optimizations listed? I mean, without comparing the actual byte code. This would be interesting to learn.

Comment: It's worth noting that the information is rarely very useful. GCC optimises almost entirely in GIMPLE and RTL, it's very hard to go back to see what "line" these statements came from. Especially if it uses case analysis, then it has to backtrack and find the specific case of something it is referring to.... and so forth.

Comment: @AlecTeal Good point, thanks.

Comment: Not worth a vote-down to me, but: "This question does not show any research effort" holds true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

the `-fopt-info` family of switches causes the optimizer to dump out information to `stderr` (or a file if you prefer). In particular, `-fopt-info-missed` can be useful to see why an optimisation *could not* be applied.

There are quite a few different combinations available. From the linked page:

> For example,
>
> ```
>           gcc -O3 -fopt-info-missed=missed.all
> ```
>
> outputs missed optimization report from all the passes into missed.all.
>
> As another example,
>
> ```
>   gcc -O3 -fopt-info-inline-optimized-missed=inline.txt
> ```
>
> will output information about missed optimizations as well as optimized locations from all the inlining passes into inline.txt.

Comment: Relevant page now (due to link rot): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're really looking for which flags are applied for a given optimization level, just look it up in the manual pages: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: These flags are not the only optimizations applied. Rather these flags are _also_ applied in addition to some "hidden" optimizations.